# ui.bootstrap typeahead with blur

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I'm using angular bootstrap typeahed.

It's possibility to display not-full word in input with blur, like in https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ ?

I try do this in ui.bootstrap-typeahed, but I have only typed chars.
I use $http request to get elements for data.

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the [typeahead documentation](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#jquerytypeaheadval-val). Typeahead fills the input with the selected or autocompleted value on blur. To avoid this, `$('#selector').typeahead('val', '<contents>')` should be used instead of `$('#selector').val('<contents>')`.